# glXChooseFBConfig w/ GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_*_EXT returning no FBConfigs on Nvidia driver

Tags: c, opengl, nvidia, glx

I have an application that uses the GLX extension `texture_from_pixmap`, which requires a color buffer created using an FBConfig with GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGB_EXT, or GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGBA_EXT, per the spec.

> Only a color buffer of a GLX pixmap created using an FBConfig with
>   attribute GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGB_EXT or GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGBA_EXT
>   set to TRUE can be bound as a texture.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap.txt

My application does this, and works fine with Mesa and the Intel i965 driver, but not with the proprietary Nvidia driver.

When using glXChooseFBConfig with the Nvidia driver, no matching FBConfigs are returned, and I can't seem to figure out why.

I've made a minimal code sample that reproduces this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>

int main()
{
        Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

        if (!display) {
                printf("Unable to connect to display.\n");
                return 1;
        }

        int pixmap_config[] = {
                GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGB_EXT, True,
                GLX_NONE
        };

        int c = 0;
        GLXFBConfig *configs = glXChooseFBConfig(display, 0, pixmap_config, &c);
        if (!configs) {
                printf("No appropriate GLX FBConfig available!\n");
        } else {
                printf("Number of matching configs: %i\n", c);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

On any Nvidia graphics card I test using the proprietary driver, I get:

> No appropriate GLX FBConfig available!

Using Intel Graphics with Mesa, I get:

> Number of matching configs: 82

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glXChooseFBConfig.xml):

```
attrib_list
    Specifies a list of attribute/value pairs. The last attribute must be None.
```

Some GL implementations, such as Mesa, are more permissive, and will accept `GLX_NONE` (0x8000) terminating this list of attributes. However, the Nvidia driver does not, and will return NULL. Specifying Xlib's `None` (0) works. This is also the case for `glXCreatePixmap`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from the attributes list passed to glXChooseFBConfig (your pixmap_config[]).

I guess some driver may fill required fields with default values, and then compare its internal configurations with the requested one.

The problem is that `EXT_texture_from_pixmap` only works with pixmaps, not windows.

So, you should set the `GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE` field with a mask containing `GLX_PIXMAP_BIT` and not the default `GLX_WINDOW_BIT`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Seems to be a no go still. I added the GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE attrib with a mask containing GLX_PIXMAP_BIT, and there are still no FBConfigs returned. I also tried with the same attributes list from this example, and it still returns no configs: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux:_Using_texture_from_pixmap_extension

Comment: I've discovered the actual cause of this, and posted an answer, in case you're still curious.